# Highlighting a newly added mat-card

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a bunch of mat-cards getting displayed via data coming in through an observable as shown below. This observable `cars$` will emit a new car object when it is available causing a new mat-card to appear automatically. Is there a way to highlight this newly added mat-card for better usability ? Is there a way available in angular 6 or material-angular ?

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let car of (cars$ | async)">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            ...
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          ...
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work

.ts

```
cars$;
lastCar;

ngOnInit() {
   cars$ = this.myService.getCards().pipe(
      tap(car => this.lastCar = car)
   );
}
```

html

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let car of (cars$ | async)">
      <mat-card [ngClass]="{ 'selected': lastCar === car }">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            ...
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          ...
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```